# ActiveRecord finding from inside a serialized field

Tags: ruby, activerecord

While working with ActiveRecord I have a table which stores a serialized array of participant usernames for each row in one field. Is there an easy way to search for all rows who contain a specific user?

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :participants
end
```

I realise I could just make a new linked table for the participants, but I feel like that would increase my overhead unnecessarily -- what do you think?

Comment: There are no easy ways to search this. You could work using LIKE '%francois%john%', but if your participants aren't stored in a known order, you won't be able search effectively.  You're much better off using Greg's answer, which is to create a new table and store the association there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new table for the participants. If the usernames are already in a separate table (which I assume they are), I'd recommend making this a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right there. I've realised I can make use of a Users table elsewhere (despite the fact that it will only hold usernames and nothing else!) mind you, I'm thinking habtm might be better, but that's a well discussed debate! Thanks very much!